# How to put parameters in JSON in feature (karate framework)?

Tags: karate

I would like to send my parameters from:

```
* def d = call read ('datas.json')
```

in my method in js file:

```
* header Authorization = call read('basic-auth.js') { username: 'd.usn', password: 'd.pw' }
```

(assuming that in datas.json I have `usn` and `pw`)

instead of writing parameters '`john`' and '`secret`'

```
* header Authorization = call read('basic-auth.js') { username: 'john', password: 'secret' }
```

I'm sorry if I didn't find the information in official repo, but any answer would be very helpful: I needed this several times and didn't find an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make me worry that the Karate documentation is useless :P. Did you look at [Embedded Expressions](https://github.com/intuit/karate#embedded-expressions) ?

```
Authorization = call read('basic-auth.js') { username: '#(d.usn)', password: '#(d.pw)' }
```

By the way if `datas.json` was already in the form : `{ username: 'john', password: 'secret' }`, you could do this:

```
Authorization = call read('basic-auth.js') read('datas.json')
```

Comment: no worries, I'm just messing with you. glad these questions are being asked on stack-overflow so that others will benefit. thank you !